# Ratios between index and sequence element

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a_1\le a_2\leq\ldots$ be an infinite sequence of positive integers. A positive integer $n$ is called good if $i=na_i$ for some index $i$. For which $(m,n)$ is it true that if $m$ is good, then $n$ must be good too? If $m=n$ it's obviously true. We're looking at the integers in the sequence $1/a_1,2/a_2,3/a_3,\ldots$, which is not always increasing or decreasing.

Comment: I think you are forgotten some relation between $m$ and $n$: The phrase "For which $(m,n)$ is it true that if $m$ is good, the $n$ must be good too?" is not precise.

Comment: There's no relation - $m,n$ are just arbitrary positive integers